# MPAndroidChart: How do I remove gridlines?

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

In my `LineChart` beside the lines that are shown on the full numbers parallel to the x-axis, many horizontal gridlines are shown:

[image]

[image]

How can I get rid of these lines?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those look like axis lines. You can toggle the axis lines by calling `setDrawGridLines(false)` on each Chart axis. For example, to clear all of them simply do something like this.

```
LineChart myChart = ...;
myChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
myChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
myChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
```

Comment: Testing your code I realized that the problem was cause by the right axis. After hiding them the grid became normally and the grid lines where at the right position. I don't know why the right axis was causing that, but most important is the fact that it works now

Comment: Thank you so much, was struggling to fix it